# C++/gRPC - Async server with more than one Service

Tags: c++, grpc

I am using gRPC and I would like to build an Async server with several async services.
Here is the example code I follow:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include <grpc/support/log.h>

#ifdef BAZEL_BUILD
#include "examples/protos/helloworld.grpc.pb.h"
#else
#include "helloworld.grpc.pb.h"
#endif

using grpc::Server;
using grpc::ServerAsyncResponseWriter;
using grpc::ServerBuilder;
using grpc::ServerContext;
using grpc::ServerCompletionQueue;
using grpc::Status;
using helloworld::HelloRequest;
using helloworld::HelloReply;
using helloworld::Greeter;

class ServerImpl final {
 public:
  ~ServerImpl() {
    server_->Shutdown();
    // Always shutdown the completion queue after the server.
    cq_->Shutdown();
  }

  // There is no shutdown handling in this code.
  void Run() {
    std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50051");

    ServerBuilder builder;
    // Listen on the given address without any authentication mechanism.
    builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    // Register "service_" as the instance through which we'll communicate with
    // clients. In this case it corresponds to an *asynchronous* service.
    builder.RegisterService(&service_);
    // Get hold of the completion queue used for the asynchronous communication
    // with the gRPC runtime.
    cq_ = builder.AddCompletionQueue();
    // Finally assemble the server.
    server_ = builder.BuildAndStart();
    std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;

    // Proceed to the server's main loop.
    HandleRpcs();
  }

 private:
  // Class encompasing the state and logic needed to serve a request.
  class CallData {
   public:
    // Take in the "service" instance (in this case representing an asynchronous
    // server) and the completion queue "cq" used for asynchronous communication
    // with the gRPC runtime.
    CallData(Greeter::AsyncService* service, ServerCompletionQueue* cq)
        : service_(service), cq_(cq), responder_(&ctx_), status_(CREATE) {
      // Invoke the serving logic right away.
      Proceed();
    }

    void Proceed() {
      if (status_ == CREATE) {
        // Make this instance progress to the PROCESS state.
        status_ = PROCESS;

        // As part of the initial CREATE state, we *request* that the system
        // start processing SayHello requests. In this request, "this" acts are
        // the tag uniquely identifying the request (so that different CallData
        // instances can serve different requests concurrently), in this case
        // the memory address of this CallData instance.
        service_->RequestSayHello(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, cq_, cq_,
                                  this);
      } else if (status_ == PROCESS) {
        // Spawn a new CallData instance to serve new clients while we process
        // the one for this CallData. The instance will deallocate itself as
        // part of its FINISH state.
        new CallData(service_, cq_);

        // The actual processing.
        std::string prefix("Hello ");
        reply_.set_message(prefix + request_.name());

        // And we are done! Let the gRPC runtime know we've finished, using the
        // memory address of this instance as the uniquely identifying tag for
        // the event.
        status_ = FINISH;
        responder_.Finish(reply_, Status::OK, this);
      } else {
        GPR_ASSERT(status_ == FINISH);
        // Once in the FINISH state, deallocate ourselves (CallData).
        delete this;
      }
    }

   private:
    // The means of communication with the gRPC runtime for an asynchronous
    // server.
    Greeter::AsyncService* service_;
    // The producer-consumer queue where for asynchronous server notifications.
    ServerCompletionQueue* cq_;
    // Context for the rpc, allowing to tweak aspects of it such as the use
    // of compression, authentication, as well as to send metadata back to the
    // client.
    ServerContext ctx_;

    // What we get from the client.
    HelloRequest request_;
    // What we send back to the client.
    HelloReply reply_;

    // The means to get back to the client.
    ServerAsyncResponseWriter<HelloReply> responder_;

    // Let's implement a tiny state machine with the following states.
    enum CallStatus { CREATE, PROCESS, FINISH };
    CallStatus status_;  // The current serving state.
  };

  // This can be run in multiple threads if needed.
  void HandleRpcs() {
    // Spawn a new CallData instance to serve new clients.
    new CallData(&service_, cq_.get());
    void* tag;  // uniquely identifies a request.
    bool ok;
    while (true) {
      // Block waiting to read the next event from the completion queue. The
      // event is uniquely identified by its tag, which in this case is the
      // memory address of a CallData instance.
      // The return value of Next should always be checked. This return value
      // tells us whether there is any kind of event or cq_ is shutting down.
      GPR_ASSERT(cq_->Next(&tag, &ok));
      GPR_ASSERT(ok);
      static_cast<CallData*>(tag)->Proceed();
    }
  }

  std::unique_ptr<ServerCompletionQueue> cq_;
  Greeter::AsyncService service_;
  std::unique_ptr<Server> server_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ServerImpl server;
  server.Run();

  return 0;
}
```

I have several questions:

1. How can I add another async service?
2. With the next async service do I need another `ServerCompletionQueue*` or I can use same `ServerCompletionQueue* cq_;` from `ServerImpl` ?
3. Is it a good idea to make `CallData` an abstract class maybe so all that inherit it have `Proceed` method? If so how should it look like?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How can I add another async service?

builder.RegisterService()

> 2. With the next async service do I need another ServerCompletionQueue* or I can use same ServerCompletionQueue* cq_; from ServerImpl ?

You can use the same completion queue if you wish, but you might want to add a thread pool with each thread polling on a separate completion queue for performance.

> 3.Is it a good idea to make CallData an abstract class maybe so all that inherit it have Proceed method? If so how should it look like?

That should work. Please note that this is just one way of doing things. The tag through the completion queue gives the flexibility for other solutions. For example, another common solution is to transform the tag to a callback function, so that you can have a 'handler' for each operation.

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer @Yash. By `completion queue` do you mean `ServerCompletionQueue` ? Is it better if I have several `ServerCompletionQueue`s ?Can you please show a simple modification example for how to make the tag as a handler? This really sounds as a good option.